# MySQL - Duplicate rows in a table with different column value determined by JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, sql-insert

I'm having a bit of difficulty writing an INSERT statement to duplicate rows, but with a different KEY value defined in another table. The KEY may not necessarily have the same value, so that's where the JOIN comes in.

```
Roles
RoleID     Name
-------------------------
3          ROLE_ADMIN
12         ROLE_OPERATOR_ADMIN
13         ROLE_CARD_ADMIN

OperatorRoles
RoleID     OperatorUserID
-------------------------
3          5
3          7
```

What I need to do, is assign all OperatorRoles.OperatorUserID users both Roles of ROLE_OPERATOR_ADMIN and ROLE_CARD_ADMIN, then remove any OperatorRoles.OperatorUserID rows that have a role of ROLE_ADMIN (essentially breaking the ROLE_ADMIN role in to the two).

```
OperatorRoles
RoleID     OperatorUserID
-------------------------
12         5
12         7
13         5
13         7
```

This is what I have come up with so far, but it attempts to insert more records than it should:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO OperatorRoles (RoleID, OperatorUserID)
SELECT r.RoleID, opRoles.OperatorUserID
FROM Roles r JOIN OperatorRoles opRoles ON r.RoleID = r.RoleID
WHERE r.Name = 'ROLE_OPERATOR_ADMIN';
```

This should be simple, but I can't make it work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking through this again with what @Gordon-Linoff posted, I came up with this and it did what I wanted:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO OperatorRoles(RoleID, OperatorUserID)
SELECT nr.newRoleID, opRoles.OperatorUserID
FROM
    (SELECT r1.RoleID AS newRoleID
    FROM Roles r1
    WHERE r1.Name IN ('ROLE_OPERATOR_ADMIN' , 'ROLE_CARD_ADMIN')) nr
CROSS JOIN OperatorRoles oproles
JOIN Roles r2 ON opRoles.RoleID = r2.RoleID
WHERE r2.Name = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
```

Comment: This is essentially the second query in my answer.  The tables in the `from` clause have just been rearranged to put the `cross join` first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically want something like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO OperatorRoles (RoleID, OperatorUserID)
    SELECT nr.NewRoleId, opRoles.OperatorUserID
    FROM Roles r JOIN
         OperatorRoles opRoles
         ON r.RoleID = r.RoleID CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT 12 as NewRoleId UNION ALL SELECT 13) nr
    WHERE r.Name = 'ROLE_ADMIN';

DELETE opRoles
    FROM OperatorRoles opRoles
         ON r.RoleID = r.RoleID
    WHERE r.Name = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
```

This sounds like a one-time operation, so the first query just uses the role ids, instead of joining back to get the names.  But, you could write it as:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO OperatorRoles (RoleID, OperatorUserID)
    SELECT nr.NewRoleId, opRoles.OperatorUserID
    FROM Roles r JOIN
         OperatorRoles opRoles
         ON r.RoleID = r.RoleID CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT RoleId as NewRoleId
          FROM Roles r
          WHERE r.Name IN ('ROLE_OPERATOR_ADMIN', 'ROLE_CARD_ADMIN')
         ) nr
    WHERE r.Name = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
```

Comment: Thanks. This didn't produce the results as expected. I am OK with having two separate queries to ensure the correct number of results. I have modified your query to view the results for each. This query returns 359 rows, so any INSERT I would expect to INSERT the same count: `SELECT opRoles.* FROM OperatorRoles opRoles
JOIN Roles r ON opRoles.RoleID = r.RoleID
WHERE r.Name = 'ROLE_ADMIN';`

Comment: Not enough space to add the modified query above. Here it is: `INSERT IGNORE INTO OperatorRoles (RoleID, OperatorUserID)
    SELECT nr.NewRoleId, opRoles.OperatorUserID
    FROM Roles r JOIN OperatorRoles opRoles ON r.RoleID = r.RoleID CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT RoleId as NewRoleId
          FROM Roles r
          WHERE r.Name = 'ROLE_OPERATOR_ADMIN'
         ) nr
 WHERE r.Name = 'ROLE_ADMIN';` This produces 2435 INSERT rows.